# Arranging 3 items in 7 spots

Tags: combinatorics

I just wanted to make sure my answer to a problem is correct.

If we have 3 different items, how many ways can we arrange them amongst 7 spots? What if each item was exactly the same and we didn't care about the order of the 3 items?

If we always pick the same item first and so on, we get 7 * 6 * 5 because for the first item we have 7 possible spots then 6 then 5. Then by symmetry we multiply by 3! to account for the number of possible permutations of the items to get 7!3!/4!? Then we could divide by 3! to drop off all permutations of items to get 7!/4! .

Another way I though about it was we have 7 total items, one group of 3 and one of four. 7!/4! would drop all permutations of the group of 4 which would be a sort of parallel to having 3 items in 7 spaces where we care about the order. From that we could drop all permutations of 3! to get 7!/4!3!.

The numbers seem off. Where did I go wrong? I'm guessing somewhere with the 7!3!/4!

Comment: If the items are distinghuishable then there are $7\times6\times5$ possibilities. Multiplication afterwards by $3!$ is wrong. All permutations are allready counted. If the items "loose" their being distinghuishable, then there is multiple counting that must be repaired by *dividing* by $3!$.

Comment: I was having trouble seeing how that is the case though. If I have 3 items b,c,d and I always pick b first then c then d, there are 7*6*5 possibilities. But what if we allow any permutation of b,c,d we would have to multiply by 3!, no?

Comment: You are confusing in the second para when you say you have 7 items

Comment: The 7 possibilities have already considered the first object being anywhere

Comment: @Shailesh I wanted to think about the problem in a different way as many problems may be expressed in different ways but give the same final answer.

Comment: That's perfectly fine as long as you do not double count

Comment: Well actually it is the fourth para

Comment: @Shailesh where is the mistake of double counting in the fourth? I think it's only in the 3rd, no?

Comment: Sorry I cannot come to chat right now otherwise would have loved to clarify your thinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers the question posed in your first comment under the question.

First for convenience let's make it smaller:

Suppose there are $2$ items $b,c$ and $3$ spots. First I pick $b$ and place it on one of the $3$ spots. Possible result:

- $b..$
- $.b.$
- $..b$

Now I take $c$ and place it on one of the remaining spots. Possible results:

- $bc.$ or $b.c$
- $cb.$ or $.bc$
- $c.b$ or $.cb$

If I permute $b$ and $c$ then will I get any results that were not allready there? No! So multiplying by $2!$ would be wrong here.

Comment: That cleared up my misunderstanding. Is there any way to intuitively have know that? I mean now it makes sense but after the fact. I would want to be able to recognize this the next time I see it put in other words.

Comment: If you handle like this (give $b$ a spot, then give $c$ a spot, et cetera) then it is unthinkable that any possibility is missed out. So permutation will not create new possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume the 3 items are same, then it is not possible to order them.
So the answer is simply in how many ways you can select 3 spots out of the 7.

Which is ${7}\choose3$=$\frac{7!}{3!4!}$.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume all three items are distinct then there are 7 places you can place the first item, 6 places remaining to place the second item and finally 5 places to place the final item making

$$7 \times 6 \times 5 = 210 \text{ distinguishable solutions}$$

Now if the items are not distinct there will be fewer distinguishable solutions not more. We can organise 3 items in $3 \times 2 \times 1 = 3! = 6$ ways so we divide by 3! not multiply giving:

$$\dfrac{7 \times 6 \times 5}{3 \times 2 \times 1} = \dfrac{210}{6} = 40 \text{ distinguishable solutions}$$

---

To try and explain further lets say there are three balls red, green and blue as you have already worked out this gives you 210 permutations.  Now imagine a blind man who can not see the balls but can feel them.  To him because the balls all feel the same and we can arrange 3 objects in $3! = 6$ ways you can distinguish 6 times the number of solutions than he can. Because you can see the colours while he can not.

Because of this we divide by 6 instead of multiply.

Comment: I understand but I'm having trouble with this one point. 
     
I was having trouble seeing how that is the case though. If I have 3 items b,c,d and I always pick b first then c then d, there are 7*6*5 possibilities. But what if we allow any permutation of b,c,d we would have to multiply by 3!, no? Where is my thinking faulty here?

Comment: @Tantilization I've edited my answer to try and explain why you divide instead of multiply.